# navigationController?の「?」の意味

Tags: swift

```
@objc private func didTapRegister() {
    let vc = RegisterViewController()
    vc.title = "Create Account"
    navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
```

Comment: この辺の記事が参考になりそうです。[どこよりも分かりやすいSwiftの"?"と"!"](https://qiita.com/maiki055/items/b24378a3707bd35a31a8), [Swiftとkotlinの⁉（optional型、nullable）の考察](https://www.webbanana.org/goroku/2018/07/21/343.php)

Comment: ありがとうございます!

Comment: @kunif コメントでは無く回答をするようにして下さい。

Comment: @Чайка さん、単純な内容ではあるけれども一度も使ったことが無い言語なので紹介だけにしました。回答は他の人でも自己回答でも良いと思われます。

Answer (score 2):

```
navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
```

これは、**Optional Chaining**と呼ばれるSwiftの構文のひとつです。

[Optional Chaining - The Swift Programming Language](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/OptionalChaining.html)

Swiftには、そのまま書こうとすると複数行になる、そこそこ複雑な処理を、1行に短縮してしまう構文がいくつもあり、Optional Chainingはそのひとつです。上の1行を、Optional chainingを使わずに書くと、このようになるでしょう。

```
if navigationController != nil {
    let navigation = navigationController!
    navigation.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
}
```

日本語で書くなら、「もし`UIViewController`のプロパティである`navigationController`の値が`nil`でなければ、`navigationController`をUnwrapし、`UINavigationController`のメソッド`pushViewController`〜を実行する」となるでしょう。